# I want to send event from my service file to renderer js in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

This is my file structure I have a function in parser.service.js which is doing some sequential work I want to send some event that will renderer.js know that 1step is done or 2nd step is done and so on....
[image]

i am using parser.service.js in queue.service.js and there is a function in queue.service.js which i am using in main.js. I tried to use  `mainWindow.webContents.send` from main.js it is working as expected but I need to use in that service file

I also created a function getMainWindow in main.js and export this

```
function getMainWindow() {
  return mainWindow
}

module.exports = {
  getMainWindow
}
```

and I import the above function but i am getting undefined in getMainWindow.

I also tried to make a function in renderer.js and import it in parser.service.js but i am getting an error

PS: I am using elctron v11